# How to convert VB script to PHP script with VARIANT class

Tags: php, vba, com, variant

I can sample a VBScript to take advantage of functions from .dll files.

And I can use the .dll file also in PHP with the COM class, but there is one function that I cannot complete, which must send parameters that seem like arrays.

Please help to complete this function.
This FalcoNetworkLib.dll is a library to send & get data from hardware. I've tried with create param as array but still get an error.

This is the VBScript sample :

```
Option Explicit
Dim cmdobj As New FalcoNetworkLib.FalcoCommandClient

Private Sub AddCard()
    Dim msg As String  
    Dim nResult As Integer
    Dim param As FalcoNetworkLib.CardDbStruct
    Dim param.CardNo = 1
        param.PinNo = 0
        param.AccessTimeZone = 1
        param.LiftAccessLvl = 1

   nResult = CommandObj.FalcoQuickSetCardDb("192.168.0.23", "2003", 0, param, msg)

   If nResult <> 0 Then
       MsgBox msg
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is sample VB Script :

Comment: `...but still get an error` ... what error?

Comment: This is VBA not VBScript.